# Does WildFly 8 support EclipseLink JPA and EclipseLink MOXy as JAXB and JSON provider

Tags: json, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy, wildfly

Due to some unavoidable circumstances we have to migrate from Glassfish 4 to WildFly 8 application server. Currently we are almost to the completion of development of RESTful services using EclipseLink JPA and EclipseLink MOXy as JAXB and JSON provider. Due to the time constrain and amount of rework, it seems difficult to move from existing implementation. Is there a way by which we can use EclipseLink MOXy as JAXB and JSON provider and EclipseLink JPA on WildFly 8? If so can someone please provide steps to migration?

Answer (score 0):

[**EclipseLink MOXy**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) offers JSON-binding through our `MOXyJsonProvider` class which implements the standard JAX-RS classes: `MessageBodyReader` & `MessageBodyWriter` (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html).  This means it can be leveraged in any JAX-RS implementation.

For XML-Binding in JAX-RS, it may be as simple as adding a `jaxb.properties` file in the same package as your domain model specifying MOXy as your JAXB provider (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).  If that doesn't work, you could do the following:

1. Implement a JAX-RS `ContentResolver` that returns a MOXy instance of `JAXBContext` (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/moxys-xml-metadata-in-jax-rs-service.html).
2. Implement a `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` that interacts with MOXy.